# Every prime that is bigger than two is odd....

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics

I have the following statement taken from the teacher's book. It states:

For every number $x$, if $x$ is prime and $x>2$ then $x$ is odd

$$\forall x[(prime(x) \land (x>2)) \rightarrow odd(x)]  $$
$$ \equiv \forall x[\lnot(prime(x) \land (x>2)) \lor odd(x)]  $$
$$ \equiv \forall x[\lnot(prime(x) \land (x>2)) \lor\lnot even(x)]  $$
$$ \equiv \forall x[\lnot((prime(x) \land (x>2)) \land even(x)]  $$
$$ \equiv \lnot\exists x[(prime(x) \land (x>2)) \land even(x)]  $$

Which is also re-written as: It is not true that there exists a prime number that is greater than 2 and is even...

My problem with this is, aren't all prime numbers bigger than two odd? And if so, how does the last statement come into play? Isn't this just a huge contradiction or am I not seeing this?

Comment: I don't see why this is a contradiction: the last statement is perfectly right.

Comment: All primes greater than 2 are odd. Think about it, if it is even and greater than 2, then that number divides 2 - the definition of being even - so an even number greater than 2 cannot be prime

Comment: Yes, "all prime numbers bigger than two are odd" and "it is not the case that there exists an even prime number greater than two" are equivalent. What makes you think they aren't?

Comment: Oh my...I see what happened... I had odd in my head the whole time and it just wouldn't click to me... You're absolutely right..I'll erase this like it never happened

Comment: All primes are odd. Except $2$, which is the only even prime, and that's very odd. Therefore, all primes are odd. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the equivalences are completely correct, and amount to:

- Every prime greater than $2$ is odd; and
- No even number greater than $2$ is prime;

being equivalent statements.